# What happens if demand for bonded validators is greater than 256?

Tags: casper

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1322/136) suggests there will be a maximum of 256 bonded validators for Casper. What if 257 nodes want to become bonded validators?

Is there a race? What's the consensus mechanism to pick 256 bonded validators? Can this lead to instability in Casper?

Answer (score 2):

The latest discussions indicate that there will be a bonding period of a certain number of days, after which time a new round of picking validators begins. That does not mean you cannot be a validator twice or even three times in a row, it will all depend on the algorithm that is put in place to handle that.

Comment: could you provide a source(s) for "the latest discussions" ?

Comment: https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/28/understanding-serenity-part-2-casper/#comment-2442186776

Answer (score 1):

This has not been fully disclosed yet, I heard it was on a rotation type basis so validators are cycled within the network. What the specifications of it currently are have not yet been released.

Most likely it will be date cycled. Or have some sort of a randomizer for participants.

Comment: in absence of a quoted source this does appear to be hearsay... it would be very useful to be able to expand on the argument and the sources...